# What kind of tub spout connector is this?

Tags: plumbing, bathtub, plumbing-fixture

The diverter in my bathtub spout has stopped working, and I want to replace the spout. When I removed it, I found this adapter, which appears to be soldered to the copper pipe (or at least I was unable to remove it, and I don’t see any threads behind it).

Can anyone identify what type of adapter this is, or help me find a spout that might fit? Otherwise, I’m afraid I’ll need to bring in a plumber to give me a more standard setup with a 1/2” nipple coming out from the wall. Really hoping I can avoid that expense.

[image: Bath tub spout adapter]

The outer diameter of the threaded part at the back is about 1-1/4”.  I’ve been unable to find any spouts that fit that. All the ones I’ve found fit only 1/2” or 3/4” pipe.

There are no marking on the adapter or the old spout, so I’m not sure what brand they are.

Comment: Looks like solder at the front of it, too. Weird one. I'd guess the o-ring was removed and this was soldered over the pipe stub sticking out of the wall, o-ring replaced, spout slipped over and screwed on.

Comment: For anyone finding this down the line, I had the same fitting on mine, but none of the pipe was sticking out of the front so it looked a bit different. Ed's answer totally did it for me, so definitely give it a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t know the brand but a plumber is not needed you could do it with a 45$ torch if you don’t have one.

I would pull the o ring and heat the end with a torch using players to hold the outer brass (yellow metal), make Sure to put some wet towels down as you slip the fitting off you don’t want the hot solder to damage the tub.  I like mapp Gas torches over propane they get hotter and make removal of sweated parts easier. Mapp has is the yellow bottle, my torch can use both types some built for propane can’t handle the higher heat of mapp gas. Then a new spigot for copper pipe could be installed.

Comment: I don’t have a torch, but could a heat gun do it?

Comment: No , that’s why I mentioned the type of torch that would be best in my opinion , much cheaper than a plumber and now you would have a tool that can be used for more than this one job at less than the cost of a plumber. A hair dryer or even a heat gun is not close to the 700 or so degrees Fahrenheit needed to melt solder.

Comment: Well, I had a plumber come out this morning, and they did... exactly this. (And yes, buying a torch would’ve been much cheaper. I basically called the plumber because I didn’t quite trust myself with a torch.)

Comment: Understandable but I hoped you could watch and possibly next time you can give it a try.

Comment: Thank you for this answer question and answer! I managed to find this based on mine looking the same as the picture and was able to take the fitting off with a blow torch. I only had a propane torch but it worked just fine. I only had to heat it for less than a minute and it came right off with a light pull.

Comment: @BenWyatt Also I'd like to thank you for saying that the plumber just did this because that gave me the courage to try torching it despite some trepidation

Answer (score 1):

I wanted too add on to this for anyone else with the same question. This is a Delta tub faucet adapter. I was able to find a delta tub faucet at home depot and it screwed right on to it. The adapter comes in the package with it, but because it was already installed I just took it out and the faucet screwed right on. It was like $35.

Comment: Do you happen to have the model number of your Delta tub spout?

Answer (score 0):

I had same. Its a Delta Faucet adapter. Should be a screw under, right by the wall. Google dalta faucet adapter and you will see it comes with screw.

Comment: The OP left a comment that the plumber needed a torch as was suggested in an existing answer.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/160717)